# How to set a value using Mutators in a model?

Tags: laravel

I have a model where I am using a mutator for logged in user, assign id. But the value is not passed.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Pass extends Model
{

use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'user_id',
    'source',
    'category_id',
];

public function setUserIdAttribute()
{
    $this->attributes['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has built-in methods to appends attributes to your model output. If for any reason, you cannot use those default methods, you can use `setRawAttributes` to dynamically add the field to your model. But laravel standard way should be better.

```
protected $attributes;

public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->setRawAttributes(array(
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id), true);
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [append](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) Laravel documentation. Adding your attributes to the `protected $appends` array should add your attribute to your final model output.

So try:

```
protected $appends = ['user_id'];
```